# Python curses getch() always returns -1 if data is piped to my program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-curses

I want to read data piped into my program and then take a user input using curses. I have the following code:

```
import curses
import sys
import select

def read_piped_data():
    data = ""
    while(sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin,],[],[],0.0)[0]):
        x = sys.stdin.read(1)
        if(len(x) == 0): break
        data += x
    sys.stdin = open("/dev/tty")
    return (data if len(data) > 0 else None)

def main(stdscr):
    data = read_piped_data()
    if(data != None): do_something1(data)
    curses.raw()
    stdscr.keypad(True)
    stdscr.timeout(0)

    while(True):
        ch = stdscr.getch()
        if(ch == -1): continue
        if(not do_something2(stdscr,ch)): break

curses.wrapper(main)
```

When I execute the above using:

```
$ python3 test.py
```

Everything works perfectly: `do_something1()` is not called but `do_something2()` is called whenever I press any key. But when I pipe something as:

```
$ ls | python3 test.py
```

My code fails: `do_something1()` is called and it correctly processes the piped-data but `do_something2()` is never called and my program is basically in an infinite loop, not registering any key-presses!

Keeping or removing the `sys.stdin = open("/dev/tty")` has no effect. In another stackoverflow answer I found this solution to make input() work (after reading from pipe). Although input() works after I reassign stdin, getch() doesn't.

Even if I do not read the piped data, just piping some command to my program is enough to mess with curses getch() preventing it from ever reading any key presses.

I am using curses with Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04. How can I "reactivate" input in curses after having read from pipe?

Comment: It looks like your `select` loop stops if it outraces the input, even if more input could be coming later. That doesn't sound like the right thing to do.

Comment: Even if you are right: in my particular case (with the "ls" example), the entire piped output is correctly processed. My problem is with the getch( ). Even if I choose not to read the piped data at all, just piping the output of some command to my program is enough to mess up my curses getch() from ever reading anything!

Comment: Reassigning `sys.stdin` doesn't change your program's actual stdin. You'll probably have to mess with file descriptors and `os.dup2`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because stdin is not guaranteed to be assignable?
At C, I have no problem with this:

```
freopen("/dev/tty","r",stdin);
```

And reassigning with fopen is also working here.

Comment: I thought there is python equivalent. I dont know.